# Set background color on even or odd based on array - ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to set different background based on the sections that i have on my page.

```
  console.log(currentPage.sections)
  // Array(10)
```

Based on that i am guessing which number is odd and which not

```
  const isItOdd = currentPage?.sections.map((section, i) => i % 2)
  // output : [ 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 ]
```

Further than that i am giving the data to my `styled-component` so that i can change the background as i wish

```
<Container isOdd={isItOdd}>
```

Furthermore i style my component like this

```
export const Container = styled.div<{ isOdd?: number[] }>`
  background: ${({ isOdd }) => (isOdd ? 'salmon' : 'white')};
`
```

But unfortunately i'm not getting the result that i need. The only color that is displayed is the `salmon`. So what am i doing wrong ?
Can someone expplain me ?

***EDIT*** : The final result that i want is to have something like this :

[image]

Comment: *But unfortunately i'm not getting the result that i need* - please explain what you mean by this.

Comment: @BrianThompson I've made an edit. I think is more clear now

Comment: `isItOdd` is an array, not a boolean. So it will always be truthy.

Comment: This was also my attempt , but it seems that is showing only value and not both `background: ${({ isOdd }) => (isOdd === 0 ? 'salmon' : 'white')};`

Comment: Did you know you can achieve that in pure CSS with the pseudo-class `:nth-child(even)` and `:nth-child(odd)` directly? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: I didn't know about this pseudo class. Thanks for the advice. It seems to work like a charm. Cheers mate !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Brian Thompson suggested. We should look more deeply to fix this problem here. [CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

At least this worked for me and fixed my problem.
As he mentioned my current array to display a color was not correct.
Because i was doing a check upon an array. And an array has always truthy value.

The answer here is to use psuedo classes and based on them render our color as we wish

```
import { css } from '@emotion/core'

export const Container = styled.div<{ isOdd?: number[] }>`
  ${({ isOdd }) =>
    isOdd &&
    css`
      &:nth-child(even) {
        background: salmon;
      }

      &:nth-child(odd) {
        background: white;
      }
    `}
`
```